# RASA Installation Erorr ('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1158)

Tags: installation, rasa-core

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6g6sogy5\\gevent\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6g6sogy5\\gevent\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6g6sogy5\gevent\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6g6sogy5\gevent\
    Complete output (234 lines):
    _configtest.c
    _cffi_backend.c
    c/_cffi_backend.c(370): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(371): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(1062): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(1071): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(1096): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(1119): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(1138): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(1152): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(1301): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(1303): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(1653): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(1654): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(1656): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(1668): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(1669): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(1672): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(1691): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(1735): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(1800): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(1802): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(1813): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(1816): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(2206): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(2211): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(2215): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(2230): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(2289): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(3195): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(3910): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(4010): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(4126): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(4167): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(4685): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(4703): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(4844): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(4835): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(4856): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(5250): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(5297): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(5304): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(5523): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'unsigned short', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(5652): warning C4267: 'function': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(5656): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(5672): warning C4267: 'function': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(5685): warning C4267: 'function': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(5714): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(5764): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(5849): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'long', possible loss of data
    c/_cffi_backend.c(6311): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\parse_c_type.c(218): warning C4267: 'return': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\parse_c_type.c(287): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\parse_c_type.c(341): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'intptr_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\parse_c_type.c(445): warning C4244: 'return': conversion from 'intptr_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\realize_c_type.c(425): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'intptr_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\realize_c_type.c(430): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'intptr_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\realize_c_type.c(448): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'intptr_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\realize_c_type.c(460): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'intptr_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\realize_c_type.c(559): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'intptr_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\realize_c_type.c(621): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'intptr_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\realize_c_type.c(700): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'intptr_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\realize_c_type.c(753): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'intptr_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\lib_obj.c(128): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'intptr_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\lib_obj.c(304): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'intptr_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\lib_obj.c(356): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'intptr_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\lib_obj.c(382): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'intptr_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\lib_obj.c(403): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'intptr_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\lib_obj.c(417): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'intptr_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\cdlopen.c(169): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\cdlopen.c(214): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\cdlopen.c(246): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\cdlopen.c(247): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\cdlopen.c(259): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\cdlopen.c(260): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\cdlopen.c(280): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\cdlopen.c(300): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\cdlopen.c(301): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\cdlopen.c(306): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\cdlopen.c(326): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\cdlopen.c(330): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\c\call_python.c(110): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'intptr_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    ffi.c
    prep_cif.c
    c/libffi_msvc\prep_cif.c(166): warning C4267: '+=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
    types.c
    _cffi_backend.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit__cffi_backend' specified multiple times; using first specification
       Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\c\_cffi_backend.cp38-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\c\_cffi_backend.cp38-win_amd64.exp
    Generating code
    Finished generating code
    LINK : fatal error LNK1158: cannot run 'rc.exe'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\python38\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 534, in link
        self.spawn([self.linker] + ld_args)
      File "c:\python38\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 557, in spawn
        return super().spawn(cmd)
      File "c:\python38\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 910, in spawn
        spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run)
      File "c:\python38\lib\distutils\spawn.py", line 38, in spawn
        _spawn_nt(cmd, search_path, dry_run=dry_run)
      File "c:\python38\lib\distutils\spawn.py", line 80, in _spawn_nt
        raise DistutilsExecError(
    distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1158

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\python38\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 172, in run
        cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 158, in call_command
        self.run_command(cmdname)
      File "c:\python38\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install_lib.py", line 11, in run
        self.build()
      File "c:\python38\lib\distutils\command\install_lib.py", line 107, in build
        self.run_command('build_ext')
      File "c:\python38\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 84, in run
        _build_ext.run(self)
      File "c:\python38\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "c:\python38\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
        self._build_extensions_serial()
      File "c:\python38\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_serial
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 205, in build_extension
        _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
      File "c:\python38\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 550, in build_extension
        self.compiler.link_shared_object(
      File "c:\python38\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 713, in link_shared_object
        self.link(CCompiler.SHARED_OBJECT, objects,
      File "c:\python38\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 537, in link
        raise LinkError(msg)
    distutils.errors.LinkError: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1158

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\setup.py", line 186, in <module>
        # libev_vfd.h, can't be included, linked, and used: it uses
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\python38\lib\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup
        raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
    SystemExit: error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1158

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1144, in run_setup
        run_setup(setup_script, args)
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 253, in run_setup
        raise
      File "c:\python38\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "c:\python38\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
        saved_exc.resume()
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
        six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2cj4at_x\cffi-1.13.2\setup.py", line 186, in <module>
        # libev_vfd.h, can't be included, linked, and used: it uses
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\python38\lib\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup
        raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
    SystemExit: error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1158

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6g6sogy5\gevent\setup.py", line 427, in <module>
        run_setup(EXT_MODULES, run_make=_BUILDING)
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6g6sogy5\gevent\setup.py", line 328, in run_setup
        setup(
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 139, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 716, in fetch_build_eggs
        resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 780, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1065, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 786, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 679, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 705, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 890, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1158, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1146, in run_setup
        raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1158
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output
```

I am trying to install the rasa framework on my laptop. I have already installed a new version of pip and python and also I installed VisualStudio 2019 and already add to the path variable of 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\arm64' but I still get this error how can I solve it?
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please upgrade setup.py by

pip install --upgrade setuptools

This worked for me.

Comment: After doing this I try to  install a rasa and I still get an error of  "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow~=1.15.0 (from rasa~=1.5.1->rasa-x) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow~=1.15.0 (from rasa~=1.5.1->rasa-x)"

Comment: TensorFlow is not compatible with python 3.8. that is the reason for having this error

Comment: Hello @DilrukshikaRajapakshe ,thier are installation issues for rasa in Windows.To avoid all those I installed python using chocolatey and then installed rasa in it.I recommend you to use python 3.6 as it is stable then 3.8 .Please refer the last comment of Piyush in this link.https://forum.rasa.com/t/failed-building-wheel-for-httptools-in-installing-rasa-in-windows10/15213/5     This worked for me